# AngularJS cross domain request to separate ExpressJS App hosted on Heroku

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, cross-domain

I have a stand-alone ExpressJS API that I have built that should be able to service mobile apps and web apps. I'm trying to test the API using a simple AngularJS client app that I have built. The API service runs fine when I host it locally.

I'm getting Cross Domain Request errors when trying to make a GET call to the API hosted on my external server. I'm using Chrome v39

**EDIT:** my error turns out to be an incorrect URL reference to my heroku API. Please see my answer, below.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myservice.heroku.com/some-api-endpoint?request-parameter=value. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost:5001 is therefore not allowed access.`

After reading and scanning numerous articles, I've tried the following:

### CORS Code on the API

Added to app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.statusCode = 204;
    return res.end();
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

### CORS Code on the API (Attempt 2)

Using the CORS node_module instead of the above, yields the same errors

Added to Package.json

```
"cors" : "~2.5.2"
```

Added to app.js

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

### Client Code (Attempt 1)

```
$http({
  url: 'http://myservice.heroku.com/some-api-endpoint?request-parameter=value',
  method: 'GET',
  headers : {
    "Origin" : "myclient.heroku.com",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method" : "GET",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers" : "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  }
})
```

Errors in the chrome dev console:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Origin" angular.js:9625
Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method" angular.js:9625 
Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers" angular.js:9625
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myservice.heroku.com/some-api-endpoint?request-parameter=value, which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight. (index):1
```

### Client Code (Attempt 2)

```
thePath = 'http://myservice.heroku.com/some-api-endpoint?request-parameter=value'
  +'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
$http.jsonp(thePath)
.success(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Errors received in the Chrome Dev Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : endpoint?request-parameter=value&callback=angular.callbacks_0:1
```

This has been stumping me for two days. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error turned out to be the reference to applications hosted on Heroku. I was attempting to make my get requests to `myapp.heroku.com` and not `myapp.herokuapp.com`. This is a subtle difference that caused there error.

Using cURL or typing in the request into the browser's address bar for `myapp.heroku.com` will redirect your request to `myapp.herokuapp.com` and complete the request successfully. However, made from Angular.js `$http()` function resulted in the Cross Domain error.

The simplest problems seem to cause the most confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a convoluted route for CORS. Use nodejs CORS middleware to do your stuff....
add,

```
"cors": "^2.5.1",
```

to your dependencies in package.json & in app module,

```
var cors = require('cors');
//add cors to do the cross site requests
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Hi @Madhavan, I've tried that and continue to receive Cross Domain errors. Please see the update to my question

Comment: jsonp & cors are two different concepts. when you have enabled CORS, you can directly use get (or) put whatever you want, but not $http.JSONP...